# Retrieve more than 19 results with AbderaClient? (pagination issue I guess)

Tags: java, pagination, apache-abdera

The manual query in the browser gives 1305 results:
http://www.gahetna.nl/beeldbank-api/opensearch/?q=Leiden

But my code with Abdera (below) returns just 19 results. This must be due to pagination. How do I access all the pages of results? Thx!

```
        List<NationaalArchiefDoc> docs = new ArrayList();
        Abdera abdera = new Abdera();
        AbderaClient client = new AbderaClient(abdera);
        searchString = searchString.replaceAll(" ", "+");

        ClientResponse resp = client.get("http://www.gahetna.nl/beeldbank-api/opensearch/?q=" + searchString.trim());

        if (resp.getType() == ResponseType.SUCCESS) {
            Document docAbdera = resp.getDocument();
            Element elementAbdera = docAbdera.getRoot();

            Iterator<Element> elementIterator = elementAbdera.getElements().get(0).getElements().iterator();
            System.out.println("number of docs found: " + elementAbdera.getElements().get(0).getElements().size());

            //looping through the 19 items
            while (elementIterator.hasNext()) {
                NationaalArchiefDoc doc = new NationaalArchiefDoc();
                Element element1 = elementIterator.next();
                // more actions in the loop...
            }
        }
```